# Navbar % of Page Height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

All I wanted was my Navbar to be a percentage of the pages height 5% with a minimum of say 128px this way my logo would always be at least 128px or larger.

The issue is that some reason this is just filling the page and appears to be using the logos size.

Code:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.navbar>.container-fluid
.navbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-header,
.navbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-header>.navbar-brand{
  height: inherit;
}

.navbar>.container-fluid {
  margin-left:  18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OG Visuals</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/telegram-logo_318-102687.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg" alt="Logo" /></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: I have seen this working after setting  html, body {height:100%;} but are you really sure this is what you want? 5% height is visually different on a landscape desktop than in a portrait tablet, or mobile phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `height: 5vh;  min-height: 128px;` to `navbar-header`, `height: 100%` to `container-fluid` and `height: inherit` to `navbar-header` and `navbar-brand`

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

.navbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-header, .navbar>.container-fluid>.navbar-header>.navbar-brand{
  height: inherit;
 } 

.navbar>.container-fluid {
  margin-left:  18%;
  margin-right: 18%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.navbar.navbar-default {
   height: 5vh;
   min-height: 128px; 
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OG Visuals</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="http://img.freepik.com/free-icon/telegram-logo_318-102687.jpg?size=338c&ext=jpg" alt="Logo" /></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the element (`div.navbar-brand` and `img` respectively) you'll see that first: the .navbar-brand has `height: inherit;` this means that it will inherit. So one of many ways to fix this is to give `.navbar-brand` a `height: 128px;`

Comment: try using `height: 5vh; min-height: 128px`